# Is there another name for Sql Azure's programming language?

Tags: sql-server, azure, tsql, sql-azure

According to [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336250.aspx) the sql language used on Sql Azure is called **transact-sql** (the same as on sql server).  But is this the only way to refer to programming on Sql Azure?

The Sql Azure variant of transact-sql doesn't support a bunch of features including global temporary tables, distributed queries and system tables; and has partial support for other areas.

So is calling it transact-sql appropriate and does anyone know if another name has taken unofficial hold (azure-sql, a-sql ...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know, is also called transact-sql. Is the same language, just with different features. But i also think they should give a different name like transact-azure or something like that. ;)